# ASP.NET+jQuery, how to deSerialize JSON?

Tags: jquery

I want to deserialize the JSON string below, using jQuery each function,
but the item is undefined.

there is the code below, but, in case I am using asp.net 2.0 + web service and fill the DataTable and pass to System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer class and return these JSON string.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $strJson = '[';
            $strJson += '{"Code":"a","Name":"Sam","Country":"US"},';
            $strJson += '{"Code":"b","Name":"John","Country":"CN"},';
            $strJson += '{"Code":"c","Name":"Mary","Country":"TW"}';
            $strJson += ']';
            $.each($strJson, function (key, item) {
                alert(item);
                if (key == 0) return false; //Prevent infinity loop
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using ASP.NET's Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer's [deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383812.aspx) method?

```
var result = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize($strJson);
```

Alternatively, there is [json_parse](http://www.json.org/json_parse.js)

```
var result = json_parse($strJson, [reviver])
```

> This method parses a JSON text to produce an object or array.
>   It can throw a SyntaxError exception.
>
> The optional reviver parameter is a function that can
>   filter and transform the results. It receives each of the keys and values,
>   and its return value is used instead of the original value.
>   If it returns what it received, then the structure is not
>   modified. If it returns undefined then the member is deleted.

[Working Example here](http://jsbin.com/ibapa). Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.json.org/json_parse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {

            var $strJson =  '[';
            $strJson +=  '{"Code":"a","Name":"Sam","Country":"US"},';
            $strJson +=  '{"Code":"b","Name":"John","Country":"CN"},';
            $strJson +=  '{"Code":"c","Name":"Mary","Country":"TW"}';
            $strJson +=  ']';

            var result = json_parse($strJson);

            $.each(result, function(key, item) {
             alert("Code: " + item.Code + " ,Name: " + item.Name + " ,Country: " + item.Country);
             //Taken the following out as it prevents objects after the first from being "alerted"
             //if ( key == 0) return false; //Prevent infinity loop
             });
      });
</script>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Example Page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the built-in JavaScript eval method:

```
$.each(eval('(' + $strJson + ')'), function(key, item) {
```

Incidentally, you don't need to use the $ sign for variables in JavaScript.