# how to build a string of id's from a json object

Tags: javascript, json

My json object looks like:

```
User { ID: 234, name: 'john', ..);
```

I want to build a string of all the ID's.

How can I do this? **is there a more elegant way than below?**

```
var ids = '';
for(int x = 0; x < json.length; x++)
{
      ids += json[x].Id + ",";
}
// strip trailing id
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759385/asp-netjquery-how-to-deserialize-json

Comment: What type is your `json` variable?

Comment: Your object is not valid JSON, not even valid JavaScript, and even if it was - it could only contain one single `ID` in its current form. So what does it really look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an array, use [`.push()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) to add items and [`.join()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) the result after, like this:

```
var ids = [];
for(int x = 0; x < json.length; x++)
{
      ids.push(json[x].Id);
}
var idString = ids.join(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you an array of several users, which is what your question seems to imply *(even though the example you show is neither valid JSON nor does it indicate that there is more than one object of type user)*…

```
var jsonResult = [{ID: 1, name: 'John'}, {ID: 2, name: 'Bob'}];

var ids = jsonResult.map( function(user) {return user.ID;} ).join(',');
// ids will be "1,2"
```

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript 1.8 (ECMA-262 Edition 5) you might use Array.reduce to do basically the same thing:

`[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}].reduce(function(a,b) { return a+','+b.id }, '').substr(1)`

If you prefer accumulating values in an array and concatenating them in the end do this:

`[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}].reduce(function(a,b) { a.push(b.id); return a }, []).join(',')`