# json response contains \n \r

Tags: asp.net, serialization, jquery, json.net

I'm working with ASP.NET and jQuery on client side.

I'm using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to serialize data from the DB on the server side and I'm sending it to the client when an Ajax request arrives.

When I open FireBug, I see the following json:

```
{"d":"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"CategoryID\": 1,\r\n    \"CategoryName\": \"a\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"123\",\r\n    \"CategoryType\": \"Personal\",\r\n    \"Traits\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"TraitID\": 1,\r\n        \"TraitName\": \"a\",\r\n        \"Description\": \"aaa\"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n        \"TraitID\": 1,\r\n        \"TraitName\": \"a\",\r\n        \"Description\": \"aaa\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"CategoryID\": 1,\r\n    \"CategoryName\": \"b\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"bla bla\",\r\n    \"CategoryType\": \"Professional\",\r\n    \"Traits\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"TraitID\": 1,\r\n        \"TraitName\": \"a\",\r\n        \"Description\": \"aaa\"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n        \"TraitID\": 1,\r\n        \"TraitName\": \"a\",\r\n        \"Description\": \"aaa\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"CategoryID\": 1,\r\n    \"CategoryName\": \"c\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"123\",\r\n    \"CategoryType\": \"Personal\",\r\n    \"Traits\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"TraitID\": 1,\r\n        \"TraitName\": \"a\",\r\n        \"Description\": \"aaa\"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n        \"TraitID\": 1,\r\n        \"TraitName\": \"a\",\r\n        \"Description\": \"aaa\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"CategoryID\": 1,\r\n    \"CategoryName\": \"d\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"bla bla\",\r\n    \"CategoryType\": \"Professional\",\r\n    \"Traits\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"TraitID\": 1,\r\n        \"TraitName\": \"a\",\r\n        \"Description\": \"aaa\"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n        \"TraitID\": 1,\r\n        \"TraitName\": \"a\",\r\n        \"Description\": \"aaa\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n]"}
```

My code from server side:

```
    [WebMethod]
public static string LoadRatingForm()
{
    bll_Trait t1 = new bll_Trait();
    t1.TraitID = 1;
    t1.TraitName = "a";
    t1.Description = "aaa";

    bll_Trait t2 = new bll_Trait();
    t2.TraitID = 1;
    t2.TraitName = "a";
    t2.Description = "aaa";

    bll_Trait t3 = new bll_Trait();
    t3.TraitID = 1;
    t3.TraitName = "a";
    t3.Description = "aaa";

    bll_Trait t4 = new bll_Trait();
    t4.TraitID = 1;
    t4.TraitName = "a";
    t4.Description = "aaa";



    bll_Category c1 = new bll_Category();
    c1.CategoryID = 1;
    c1.CategoryName = "a";
    c1.CategoryType = "Personal";
    c1.Description = "123";
    c1.Traits.Add(t1);
    c1.Traits.Add(t2);

    bll_Category c2 = new bll_Category();
    c2.CategoryID = 1;
    c2.CategoryName = "b";
    c2.CategoryType = "Professional";
    c2.Description = "bla bla";
    c2.Traits.Add(t3);
    c2.Traits.Add(t4);

    bll_Category c3 = new bll_Category();
    c3.CategoryID = 1;
    c3.CategoryName = "c";
    c3.CategoryType = "Personal";
    c3.Description = "123";
    c3.Traits.Add(t1);
    c3.Traits.Add(t2);

    bll_Category c4 = new bll_Category();
    c4.CategoryID = 1;
    c4.CategoryName = "d";
    c4.CategoryType = "Professional";
    c4.Description = "bla bla";
    c4.Traits.Add(t3);
    c4.Traits.Add(t4);

    List<bll_Category> list = new List<bll_Category>();
    list.Add(c1);
    list.Add(c2);
    list.Add(c3);
    list.Add(c4);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

My jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyProfile.aspx/LoadRatingForm",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var html;
                var categories = response.d;
                $.each(categories, function (i, category) {
                    // create 
                    //while (category.CategoryType == "Professional") {
                    //
                    //}

                    html += category.CategoryName + " ";
                });
                dialog.append(html);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
```

The 'dialog' variable is a jQuery UI modal dialog and the $.ajax code is in the dialog's 'open' event handler...

What should I do to make the serialization result in a "correct" json format without any '\n', '\r' and '\' ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not manually JSON serialize that List.

ASP.NET is already doing it for you automatically when you call it via POST and use a content-type of `application/json`.  So, you're ending up with a doubly serialized response, and that is why you've found that you need to parse it a second time after jQuery has already parsed it once.

If you use a return type of List and return the list directly, you should be in good shape.

More info: http://encosia.com/2011/04/13/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Answer (score 7):

You could try `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.None);`

Have you looked at this related question [ASP.NET+jQuery, how to deSerialize JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759385/asp-netjquery-how-to-deserialize-json). Might be something to do with the Content-Type header.

EDIT: See comments, there was no parsing of the JSON.

Comment: Am I missing something or don't you have to have to parse into an object first?

Comment: Of course you are right!

I added $.parseJSON and everything works now...

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

According to the JSON spec: "Whitespace can be inserted between any pair of tokens."

http://www.json.org/

So don't worry about it.

Or read about JSON formatting here http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.html

Comment: but I can't parse this json code with jQuery, so I thought that the problem is with the json I receive from the server...

I've updated the first post with the jQuery code.